# SSRS Hierarchy Recursive parent - child with multiple parent

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, hierarchy, common-table-expression

Hi I need help with setup in SSRS to properly display children in multiple parents in Hierarchy report.

This is what I have done.

```
 select * from PCA
```

This is PCA table

```
Parent      Child
ASSY1       CHILD1    
ASSY1       CHILD2    
CHILD1      ACHILD1   
CHILD1      ACHILLD2  
ACHILD1     BCHILD1   
ACHILD1     BCHILD2
```

This is the CTE in report dataset

```
 WITH tBOM AS(
 SELECT Parent,Child, 0 as BOMLevel from PCA A
 WHERE Parent='ASSY1'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT C.Parent, C.Child, BOMLevel+1 from PCA C
 INNER JOIN tBOM on tBOM.Child=C.Parent
 )
 SELECT row_number() over (Order by Parent), * FROM tBOM
```

This is the setup in SSRS rdl file. And the report when I run it. Group by Child, and I set the **recursive parent** as parent. I Also set the Group visibility so i get the plus sign to do drill down and also padding. all looks good.

[image]

Padding left is set like so:

```
=20 * Level() & "pt"
```

[image]

UNTIL: I add one more row to the table.

```
Parent  Child
ASSY1       CHILD1    
ASSY1       CHILD2    
CHILD1      ACHILD1   
CHILD1      ACHILLD2  
ACHILD1     BCHILD1   
ACHILD1     BCHILD2   
**ACHILLD2      BCHILD2**
```

I expect something below ACHILLD2 
But no: this is what I get

[image]

MORE to this. if I add more rows to increase the depth , the result will be more incorrect. For example if I add a children to BCHILD2,

[image]

But Instead I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading hours of article. I come to the conclusion that SSRS is not able to achive my end goal. *sad* I know. but it is what it is

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/724449/bug-found-when-using-the-ssrs-recursive-hierarchy-feature-with-multi-parent-relationships

> Bug Found When using the SSRS Recursive Hierarchy Feature with
>   Multi-Parent Relationships - by MichaelLee
>
> Status :  Closed   as By Design By Design
>  The product team
>   believes this item works according to its intended design.
>   A more detailed explanation for the resolution of this particular item
>   may have been provided in the comments section.
>
> Description
>
> In a SSRS report, you can create a recursive hierarchy with drill down
>   controls by following this article:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630438(v=SQL.100).aspx
>
> However, it seems that this feature does not work correctly when a
>   child has multiple parents. If a child has two parents, you would
>   expect that a child is placed under each parent. Instead, the child is
>   placed only under the parent that appears first in the SQL table. If
>   you add an additional column to the tablix and set the expression to
>   '=CountRows("RowGroupName",Recursive)', you'll notice that the total
>   records for the child is 2. So for some reason both records are being
>   placed below the first parent, even though one of the records has a
>   different parentid.
>
> Note that in my situation, the child and parent ids are of the type
>   uniqueidentifier.
>
> DETAILS Comments (2)   |   Workarounds (3)   |   Attachments (0) Sign
>   in to post a comment. Posted by Ibrahim Achkar on 4/20/2012 at 6:10 AM
>   Hello Michael, I also found this bug. Any update concerning a
>   resolution from Microsoft. As for your workaround, do you suggest
>   getting the data and setting it in a new temp table in a different
>   (1-to-1 relationship) format. With the new table at hand, do we still
>   need to use the parent grouping in SSRS or another method is required?
>
> Your assistance is highly appreciated.
>
> Thank you, Ibrahim Posted by Riccardo [MSFT] on 2/13/2012 at 5:34 PM
>   Thanks for your feedback. We're resolving this bug as By Design
>   because we associate each group with a single parent group. We don't
>   associate a group with multiple parent groups (but feel free to create
>   a Suggestion for this capability).
>
> To further explain the expected behavior, we first group the data
>   based on the GroupExpression, or the ChildID field in this case. Then
>   we evaluate the Parent expression, in this case the ParentID field,
>   for each group. Since we associate each group with a single parent
>   group, we need a single value. When an expression that should return a
>   single value refers to fields in a scope with multiple data rows -
>   this case is just one example - the behavior is officially undefined,
>   but in practice, it tends to behave like the First aggregate function,
>   which takes the first data row in scope.
>
> Riccardo Muti SQL Server Reporting Services

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a65bf4a4-e3b6-4c33-aa9e-6f7d7e4b7f5e/bill-of-materials-recursive-parent-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

> Hi duanekae, Just to confirm, I never had an adequate solution using
>   SSRS for this. I have ended up using a custom SQL function to do this.
>   I would love the get it working in SSRS though as this would be a much
>   easier solution. Wednesday, January 13, 2016 4:04 PM Quote Avatar of
>   Alex Lush - Severn Unival Alex Lush - Severn Unival

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue in SSRS and we solve it with combined ids and parentIds (concat) in order to get unique keys for recursive chain.
Taking your example:

| Id | Parent | Child | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | ASSY1 | CHILD1 | null |
| a | ASSY1 | CHILD2 | null |
| b-c | CHILD1 | ACHILD1 | a |
| b-d | CHILD1 | ACHILLD2 | a |
| c-e | ACHILD1 | BCHILD1 | b-c |
| c-f | ACHILD1 | BCHILD2 | b-c |
| d-f | ACHILLD2 | BCHILD2 | b-d |